# How do I access the values in an object inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm attempting to access values that are held inside a Class which is listed in a HashMap.

In my first class I create a HashMap which links to the "LiftingStats" class.

```
Map<String, LiftingStats> fitnessGoals = new HashMap<String, LiftingStats>();
```

In the LiftingStats class I do the following...

```
public class LiftingStats
{
   public String activity;
   public String weightType;
   public int weight;
   public double difficulty;

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class LiftingStats
    */
   public LiftingStats()
   {
      this.run();
   }

   /**
    * test method to fill values
    */
   public void run(){
      //code
      this.activity = "bench press";
      this.weightType = "Kg";
      this.weight = 100;
      this.difficulty = 8.5;
   }
```

I'm running a test method to fill the hashmap with some values

```
   public void testMethod(){
      fitness.put("activityone", new LiftingStats());
      fitness.put("activitytwo", new LiftingStats());
```

Comment: `fitness.values()` gives you a `Collection<LiftingStats>`; just iterate that.

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology. You're title question should be: "How do I access the values in an *object* inside a HashMap?"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Read values from the `fitness` map (i.e. from the `activityone` `LiftingStats` object)?

Comment: So the key is activityone & activitytwo - I want to get the instance variables that are in LiftingStats that are linked to activityone and activitytwo if that makes sense?

Comment: Just use `fitnessGoals.get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to access them.

For retrieving the value of a specific `key` entry

```
LiftingStats valueForOne = fitness.get("activityone");
```

For retrieving values without concern for keys

```
Collection<LiftingStats> values = fitness.values();
```

For retrieving key and value pairs

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, LiftingStats>> entries = fitness.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, LiftingStats> entry : entries) {
   entry.getValue();
}
```

or some variant.

Answer (score 1):

A Map is a Data Structure consisting of `Key, Value` pairs. In this case you have two keys that reference two instances of `LiftingStats` objects. To access these objects simply use your specific key to retrieve the object(s). Ex:

```
LiftingStats current = fitness.get("activityone");
```

With your reference to `current` you can perform operations on that specific `LiftingStats` object.

Similarly, you can 'daisy-chain' function calls together like this and still mutate the object within the Map. Ex:

```
fitness.get("activityone").someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt this answer to your problem :
[How to efficiently iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

```
Map<String, LiftingStats> fitnessGoals = new HashMap<String, LiftingStats>();
for (Map.Entry<String, LiftingStats> entry : fitnessGoals.entrySet())
{
    //What you need to do with your map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way by which you can access variables of an object in HashMap is by typecasting the data fetched by getValue() method of a Hashmap into the user defined class.

You can use the following code:

```
Map<String, LiftingStats> lstats= new HashMap<String, LiftingStats>();
for (Map.Entry ls:lstats.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(ls.getKey()+" "+((LiftingStats)ls.getValue()).activity);
}
```

Any variable present in the class can be accessed simply by using ((LiftingStats)ls.getValue()).*Var_name* . where Var_name is the name of any class variable.